# Error while opening Jmeter Plugin Manager (jmeter-plugins-manager-0.16)

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have added the plugin manager jar(jmeter-plugins-manager-0.16) in lib/ext folder of Jmeter. I keep getting below error message when I try to open Plugin Manager through the options. Can someone please help.

I am using proxy settings.

I tried to run the jmeter through command prompt using Jmeter.bat -H my-proxy-server -P portnumber but this also not worked.

I have also tried through command prompt using JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat
 but this command is giving me error.

```
Failed to download plugins repository. One of the possible reasons is that you have proxy requirement for Internet connection.
Please read the instructions on this page: [https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/][1]  Error's technical details:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:376)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:371)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJSON(JARSourceHTTP.java:121)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepositories(JARSourceHTTP.java:172)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepo(JARSourceHTTP.java:199)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:69)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerDialog.loadPlugins(PluginManagerDialog.java:140)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerDialog.componentShown(PluginManagerDialog.java:260)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem.actionPerformed(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:100)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you try to reach https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/ using a browser to check your proxy? Assuming you actually used your local proxy settings and not 'myproxy.com'....?

Comment: I am not able access [link]( jmeter-plugins.org/repo) through browser. I am using my local proxy setting and it is giving me this          :       [{"id":"blazemeter-debugger","name":"BlazeMeter Step-by-step Debugger","description":"This plugin enables step-by-step debugging of JMeter scripts","screenshotUrl":"https:\/\/raw.githubusercontent.com\/Blazemeter\/jmeter-debugger\/master\/src\/main\/resources\/com\/blazemeter\/jmeter\/debugger\/logo.png","helpUrl":"https:\/\/github.com\/Blazemeter\/jmeter-debugger","vendor":"BlazeMeter.com","markerClass":"com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.engine.Debugg

Comment: This means that you **have** access to the repo ;-) So your proxy works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error message when your local proxy server does not allow you to access the https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/. In order to get rid off this issue you need to provide access to https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/ and then restart the system. It worked for me.

Comment: Good that you solved it! It is always a good idea to retrace your steps and start at a point you know something works, and work your way up from there.

Comment: @Pankaj: how you have given access to  jmeter plugin url , can you please tell

Comment: @UmeshKumar If you use proxy server(as I was using at that time) I think you need to add the Urls to exceptions list of the proxy setting from internet explorer. I am really not sure about this though as I did this quite a long time ago and now I don't work on Jmeter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it after closing **all terminal windows** and re-open jmeter double-clicking /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/bin/jmeter